# With git, how do I keep track of writes to a local file every 5 seconds?

Tags: git, local, versioning

I want to run git locally and keep the changes. Do I need to run "git stash" or "git commit" on a loop? Somehow this doesn't seem like the most efficient way.

Comment: I can't think of a project that get changed every 5 seconds, that's terrifying.

Comment: something like ext3cow or tux3 would be more appropriate for this but they seem to be scarily un-updated without much help online.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. Is there any good reason why you want to use *git* for this task?

Comment: What do you mean by "run git locally and keep the changes"? You want to automatically commit a particular file every 5 seconds? _Why_?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Linux, you can use crontab to schedule whatever you want, for example executing a script every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/username/script.sh
```